# Как динамически добавить виджет?

Tags: flutter, dart

Всем привет, мне с сервера приходит json, и если is_new == treu - мне нужно отображать контейнер. Как я могу это реализовать?

Вот что я пытаюсь сделать -

```
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
  children: [
    if(HomeStore.HSisNew[itemIndex] == true) {
      return Container(
  child: Text('new'),
}
)
)
```

Comment: в каком виде у вас результаты запроса? ... я про тип данных

Comment: @МихаилРебров boolean

Comment: см ответ. Если будут вопросы - пишите. Сделал пример со списком специально, т.к. видел что у Вас там индексы каких-то элементов.

Comment: специфику обработки запроса  и построения нужного вам виджета оставляю за вами

Comment: получилось что?

Comment: @МихаилРебров Постараюсь опробовать сегодня-завтра. Сейчас, я могу вам сказать, что результаты запроса я пихаю в массив. И далее этот массив выгружаю списком. Мне не совсем понятен ваш код (я еще новичок), но я постараюсь разобраться с ним. Смогу ли я, в случае чего, обратиться к вам за помощью?

Comment: да, конечно, пишите

Comment: я вечером постараюсь подробнее решение описать, чтобы было понятнее

Comment: я там добавил небольшой разгон про асинхронные вычисления в ответ... потом если будет непонятно могу еще небольшое пояснение по поводу FutureBuilder написать

Comment: получилось что?

Comment: @МихаилРебров Вот, сейчас буду приступать, скоро отпишусь

Comment: @МихаилРебров Я попробовал, на мой взгляд, более простое решение (но не факт, что правильное) -  ` HomeStore.HSisNew[itemIndex] == null ? Colors.transparent : configColors.orange, `

Answer (score 0):

### Асинхронные вычисления

Для того чтобы решать такие задачи нужно понимать концепцию асинхронных вычислений.

Стоит понимать, что далеко не все задачи и вычисления происходят быстро и незаметно, а также далеко не все задачи и вычисления зависят от нашего приложения.
Есть множество примеров длительных вычислений и задач, которые от нас не зависят:

- построение отчетов
- обращение по сети к веб-сервисам
- обращение к базе данных
- и пр.

Все эти задачи, как правило, требуют времени.
Но вот незадача: если они будут выполняться последовательно в том же потоке что и пользовательский интерфейс, то приложение просто "повиснет" и не будет отвечать ни на какие действия пользователя до тех пор, пока данная длительная задача не завершится.

Именно поэтому во многих современных фреймворках(включая Android) запрещается выполнять такие задачи в основном потоке. А основной поток предназначается только для работы с пользовательским интерфейсом.

В то время как длительные по выполнению задачи выполняются в отдельном потоке и по завершению их выполнения, об этом уведомляется пользовательский интерфейс и происходит его обновление.

Сначала все это делалось явно и это требовало написания достаточно большого количества кода для создания асинхронных задач, колбеков и прочего. Но по мере развития данной концепции поддержку выполнения асинхронных задач начали переносить с плеч фреймворков и библиотек на конструкции самих языков.

И так появились языковые конструкции `async-await`.

В языки начали добавлять

- ключевое слово `async`, которое ставится во время определения метода, который будет выполнять асинхронную задачу.
  выполнение данного метода автоматически будет производиться в отдельном потоке
- ключевое слово `await`, которое **опционально** может ставится перед ВЫЗОВОМ асинхронного метода для ЯВНОГО ожидания результатов работы асинхронного метода.
  данное ключевое слово помогает как бы "отключить" асинхронный режим для конкретного вызова и осознанно остановить поток в котором происходит его вызов и дождаться результатов работы данного метода
  В качестве примера, такое может понадобиться в методе построения того же самого отчета: нам последовательно нужно делать обращений к базе данных и без результатов работы предыдущего вызова выполнение оставшейся части метода не имеет никакого смысла и нам проще остановиться и явно подождать.

Эти языковые конструкции позволяют избежать огромного количества дополнительного кода в котором бы создавались отдельные потоки и пр.

Остается одна проблема...
**Как получить результат выполнения асинхронного запроса?**
Это все здорово, что больше не нужно писать кучу дополнительного кода, но эти асинхронные методы должны что-то возвращать и этим чем-то нужно уметь как-то пользоваться...

Все результаты работы асинхронных методов в Dart'e оборачиваются в экземпляры [класса](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future-class.html) `Future<T>`

Соответственно если вы в асинхронном методе выполняете

```
       // возвращаем строку
return "результат работы моего асинхронного метода";
```

То он Вам вернёт `Future<String>`

Объект типа `Future` предоставляет интерфейс для доступа к результатам работы асинхронного метода.

А если быть точнее то это метод `then()` в который можно передать лямбда-выражение, которое должно будет обработать результаты вашего асинхронного метода:

```
Future<String> resultOfAsyncMethod = myAwesomeAsyncMethod();
resultOfAsyncMethod.then((value) => print(value))
                   .catchError((error) => handleError(error));
```

### Что предлагает Flutter?

Для таких вещей Flutter рекомендует использовать [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html), в который можно передать:

- результаты работы асинхронного метода в виде `Future<T>`
  в нашем конкретном кейсе мы передаем [Future](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future-class.html)<[http.Response](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/networking/fetch-data)> ибо именно его возвращает `http.get()`
- и builder который на основе данного результата сможет вам построить ваш виджет

**Что это вообще такое?**
На самом деле очень важный и полезный вопрос, потому что `FutureBuilder<T>` это обычный виджет!

```
class FutureBuilder<T> extends StatefulWidget
```

Соответственно, вы его можете вставлять и использовать везде где предполагалась работа с виджетами и вы его модете вставлять во все `child`, `children` и пр. поля предполагающие вставку виджета.

За одной единственной особенностью:
Данный виджет умеет работать с результатами работы асинхронных методов и сможет сконструировать в теле билдера любой виджет (они в зависимости от результатов работы асинхронного метода и его статуса могут отличаться)

в упрощенном виде это выглядит так:

```dart
new FutureBuilder<http.Response>(
          // делаете запрос и передаете его во future
  future: http.get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')), 
          // определяете Builder, который сотворит нужный виджет
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<http.Response> snapshot) {
    // на вход нам приходит AsyncSnapshot<http.Response>
    // и было бы неплохо проверить его состояние
    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
      case ConnectionState.none: return new Text('Ничего не происходит');
      case ConnectionState.waiting: return new Text('Ждем результаты запроса...');
      default:
        // проверяем не было ли ошибки во время выполнения запроса
        if (snapshot.hasError){
          return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        }
        else{
          // ну и если все ок, то получаем тело запроса
          String? body = snapshot.data?.body;
          return new Text('Response body: ${body}');
        }
    }
  },
)
```

Вот рабочий пример получения списка пользователей из REST API

1. тут мы делаем запрос к API,
2. и создаем на основе запроса список пользователей

```
new FutureBuilder<http.Response>(
  future: http.get(Uri.parse('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')), // a Future<String> or null
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<http.Response> snapshot) {
    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
      case ConnectionState.none: return new Text('Ничего не происходит');
      case ConnectionState.waiting: return new Text('Ждем результаты запроса...');
      default:
        if (snapshot.hasError){
          return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        }
        else{
          String? body = snapshot.data?.body;
          List<dynamic> users =jsonDecode(body!);
          List<Card> cards = <Card>[];
          for(Map<String,dynamic> user in users) {
            cards.add(Card(
                child: ListTile(
                    title: Text(user['name'])
                )
            ));
          }
          return Expanded(child: ListView(
              children: cards
          ));
        }
    }
  },
)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Отличный ответ и мне кажется он мне подходит. Я лишь хочу узнать некоторые детали.
Смотрите, мне приходит ответ с сервера в формате json. Если Там присутствует "is_new" - то я верну, например контейнер. Однако, если "is_new" там не окажется, то виджет будет пустой? Или выкинет ошибку?

Comment: Чтобы вам было понятнее, то вот как я сохраняю данные, которые приходят с сервера - 
` for(int i = 0; i < homeStore.length; i++) {
        HomeStore.HSisNew.add(homeStore[i]['is_new']);
      }`

Comment: И вот, как я отображаю данные - `child: Text(
                                                    '${HomeStore.HSid[index]}',
                                                  ),
Однако, когда дело дойдет то того момента, как is_new в массиве не окажется, я получу ошибку

И судя по всему, то что вы написали, мне это подходит, так ли это?

Comment: Как я понимаю, если все хорошо, он отобразит виджет, если нет, то нет